# improve bash script to add one more action if success

Tags: bash

I have a bash script to find out all non empty files under some directory. currently it only print the file name if found.
I would like to add one more line to print first 32 bytes in hex format.

```
#!/bin/sh

files=$(find /data/ -type f ! -empty)

for f in $files;
do
    if [ -f "$f" ]; then
        tr -d '\000' <$f | tr -c '\000' '\n' | grep -q -m 1 ^ || echo $f
    fi
done
```

I try to add one more "&& xxd -g 1 -l 32 $f" at the end but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 1):

Get the first 32 chars from the file:

```
dd if=so.bash ibs=32 count=1 2>/dev/null | od -h
```

- `dd` gets the first 32 chars
- `od -h` prints them in hex format

You could do it with xxd as well

```
xxd -l 32 $f
```

- where `$f` is the file

---

```
#!/bin/bash

files=$(find /data/ -type f ! -empty)

for f in $files
do
    if [ -f "$f" ]; then
        tr -d '\000' <"$f" | tr -c '\000' '\n' | grep -q -m 1 ^ || echo $f
        xxd -l 32 "$f"
        echo ""
    fi
done
```

- the `echo ""` is to have an empty line between each file to split the output.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is how to add this logic into the script.

Comment: Edited to add the command in your script.

Comment: Thanks, the echo $f command has a || condition before execution. I would like the same condition apply to xxd command. maybe need a if statement but not sure how to do that!

Answer (score 0):

#### Suggesting one line `gawk` script:

```
gawk 'BEGINFILE{print FILENAME}/[^\x00]/{system("xxd -l 32 "FILENAME;nextfile}' $(find /data/ -type f ! -empty)
```

#### `gawk` Explanation

##### `BEGINFILE{print FILENAME}`

```
BEGINFILE{ # before processing a file
  print FILENAME; # print the filename
}
```

##### `/[^\x00]/{system("xxd -l 32 "FILENAME);nextfile}`

```
/[^\x00]/{ # if records contains non NULL character
  system("xxd -l 32 "FILENAME); # print first 32 hex charachters
  nextfile; # read next file
}
```

Comment: Good, how can I add one more condition just like "tr -d '\000' <$f | tr -c '\000' '\n' | grep -q -m 1 ^ || echo $f", this echo $f has a condition to print. and is it possible to use awk?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but the meaning/need is questionable. It seam as  if it is already accomplished. Please explain what `"tr -d '\000' <$f | tr -c '\000' '\n' | grep -q -m 1 ^ || echo $f"` does.

Comment: The `"tr -d '\000' <$f | tr -c '\000' '\n' | grep -q -m 1 ^` part check if file contains 0x00 only, if it is, then echo the filename. otherwise do not echo the file name.

Comment: updated answer with your request. Not tested.

Answer (score 0):

Every command run in bash shell returns a value that’s stored in the bash variable “$?”.
Then the command can be split as below:

```
#!/bin/sh

files=$(find /data/ -type f ! -empty)

for f in $files;
do
    if [ -f "$f" ]; then
        tr -d '\000' <$f | tr -c '\000' '\n' | grep -q -m 1 ^
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            echo $f
            xxd -l 32 $f
        fi
    fi
done
```